# Error message using dot2texi

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex

When compiling the document below with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=0.8]
    % set node style
    \tikzstyle{n} = [draw,shape=circle,minimum size=2em, inner sep=0pt,fill=blue!20]
    \begin{dot2tex}[dot,tikz,codeonly,styleonly,options=-s -tmath]
    digraph G {
        rankdir = LR;
        node [style="n"];
        a -> b   [label="1", topath="out=45,in=135"];
        b -> c   [label="2", topath="out=90,in=135"];
        b -> a   [label="6", topath="out=-135,in=-45"];
    }
    \end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{fig:myfig} Some graph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

> Process started
>
> ERROR Failed to create xdotdata. Is Graphviz installed?
>
> ERROR Failed to parse the input data. Is it a valid dot file? Try to
>   input xdotdata directly. [...]

However, the resulting PDF file looks just fine. Any clues what might be incorrectly configured? Versions are Windows 7, Graphviz 2.30, MiKTeX 2.9, dot2tex 2.8.7.

Comment: Did you used the `-shell-escape` option for pdflatex?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino yes, the full command is `pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: since the resulting pdf file looks fine, it might be off-topic and check if your `graphviz` is configured in windows `Path`. may try removing the auxiallary files and rerun the above `pdflatex` sequence

Comment: Since the pdf file generated is fine it might be off-topic.